# How to return an action type from a method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am trying to figure out how to return an action from a method. I cannot find any examples of this online. Here is the code I am trying to run but it fails:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testAction = test("it works");
            testAction.Invoke();    //error here
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static Action<string> test(string txt)
        {
            return (x) => Console.WriteLine(txt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the parameter to the invocation not as part of the declaration.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/018hxwa8.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `textAction` is an `Action<string>`, which means you need to pass a string:

```
textAction("foo");
```

I suspect you want something like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var testAction = test();
        testAction("it works");
        // or textAction.Invoke("it works");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // Don't pass a string here - the Action<string> handles that for you..
    static Action<string> test()
    {
        return (x) => Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect that `test` is an attempt to curry `WriteLine`, so he in fact wants it to return `Action` rather than making `test` parameterless.  Both interpretations are possible given the vagueness of the question though.

Comment: @Servy Good point - that  may be the goal, but it wasn't stated, so it's difficult to tell.

Answer (score 3):

The action that you are returning accepts a `string` as it's parameter.  When you `Invoke` it you need to supply that parameter:

```
testAction("hello world");
```

Of course, your action ignores that parameter, so the more appropriate fix is to change the action so that it accepts no parameters:

```
static Action test(string txt)
{
    return () => Console.WriteLine(txt);
}
```

Now your program will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Since what you have is an `Action<String>` your invoke needs to include the string your actioning on.

```
testAction.Invoke("A string");
```

should work

Answer (score 1):

The action you want to create should be parameterless, so that you can call it without parameters. So change the return type of `test`, and also drop that `x` that you declared but never used:

```
    static Action test(string txt)
    {
        return () => Console.WriteLine(txt);
    }
```

Then the calling code will work:

```
        var testAction = test("it works"); // store the string in txt
        testAction.Invoke();
        Console.ReadLine();
```